# Sort arbitrarily typed list with possible nulls

Tags: python

I have a bunch of lists (they come from a database) and I want to sort each one as best I can. However, I don't know the types beforehand. Since they are from db, mostly there will be dates, datetimes, strings, numbers, and booleans.

**Most of the values in a given list will be of the same type**, but there will be pesky `None`s in there sometimes (the db fields are mostly nullable).

Usually if I knew the type of the list beforehand I would use something like this as my `key`:

```py
lambda el: el or 0
```

but replace 0 with whatever is most appropriate (ie `-math.inf`, `""`, `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)`, etc)

Here's what I've come up with:

```py
def sort_arbitrarily_typed_list(my_list):
    try:
        # Ideal situation - no nulls, all is happy
        return sorted(my_list)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        # Maybe it's numbers?
        return sorted(my_list, key=lambda el: el or 0)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        # Maybe strings?
        return sorted(my_list, key=lambda el: el or "")
    except:
        # Catchall: just convert everything to a string and compare them.
        return sorted(my_list, key=str)
```

Are there any problems with this approach, or is there maybe a better way? I figured `str` as the catchall would be fine...is there any case where calling `str` on a value will fail?

Comment: Is a single list guaranteed to be just one type aside from the potential `None`s? Or can the list contain mixed types?

Comment: Why do you want to retain `None`s in the sorted list? Why can't you filter them out beforehand?

Comment: @a_guest I'm trying to build a list of all the values. If there are any nulls I would like to retain them. I'm going to call `set` on this and use it to show a list of all the unique values in the list. If there are nulls I would like to retain them.

Comment: @Willow What do you mean by "null"? Do you mean `None`? Why can't you do the following: `result = sorted(x for x in my_list if x is not None)`? If you *really* like the `None`s then you can just do `result = [None]*(len(my_list)-len(result)) + result`.

Comment: This doesn't seem useful.  How can you sort dates and strings, or dates and booleans?  Why don't you just do `ORDER BY` when you read from the database?

Comment: @TimRoberts it's not sorting dates and strings in the same list. You could have one list that is a bunch of strings and `None` values, and another list that is dates and `None` values.

Comment: @a_guest yes I meant `None`. I do need to retain the `None` values. `result = [None]*(len(my_list)-len(result)) + result` seems promising, however I prefer the one-liner in @Pycopath's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort primarily by `None`-ness and secondarily by value, so it won't do comparisons of `None` and other values.

```
>>> my_list = [3, None, 1, None, 4]
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x is None, x))
[1, 3, 4, None, None]
```